Is it possible to plot a bar between two values (or major ticks) on a category axis in Excel?
I want to create a chart like in Excel (see the bar plot is between the two ticks or labels on the category axis).

Can someone please suggest if it is possible in Excel or is there any alternative to create such a chart?
Data used for the chart is below:


Use 2 charts to give 2 x-axes then overlay one on the other.
